# How am I supposed to limit up to 100 since I do not want to exceed it to 100? JAVA

Tags: java

How am I supposed to limit this value since if I eat bananas it should be increase its energy level by 10, but I have 95 energy level left so once I added the 10 to 95, it would be 105.But it still should be 100 since that is the limit of the gorilla energy level.

**Source Code**

```
public class Main {
    
    public String name;
    public int level;
    public Main()
    {
        
    }
    
    //constructors
    public Main(String name, int level) 
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.level = level;
    }
    
    //setters and getters
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }
    public void setLevel(int level) {
        this.level = level;
    }
    
    //methods
    
    public void throwSomething(Main gorilla2)
    {
        System.out.println(this.name+" throw something and will be decrease its energy level to -5");
        int newLevel = gorilla2.getLevel() - 5;
        gorilla2.setLevel(newLevel);
        System.out.println(gorilla2.getName() + " has only " + gorilla2.getLevel()+ " energy level left" );
    }
    
    public void eatBananas(Main gorilla2)
    {
        System.out.println(this.name+" eat bananas and will be increase its energy level to +10");
        int newLevel = gorilla2.getLevel() + 10;
        gorilla2.setLevel(newLevel);
        System.out.println(gorilla2.getName() + " has only " + gorilla2.getLevel()+ " energy level left" );
    }
    public void climb(Main gorilla2)
    {
        System.out.println(this.name+" has climb and will be decrease its energy level to -10");
        int newLevel = gorilla2.getLevel() - 10;
        gorilla2.setLevel(newLevel);
        System.out.println(gorilla2.getName() + " has only " + gorilla2.getLevel()+ " energy level left" );
    }
```

**Extension (Another file to call the Main class)**

```
public class Main1 extends Main {
public static void main(String[]args)
{
Main gorilla1 = new Main ("Gorilla", 100);
Main gorilla2 = new Main ("Gorilla", 100);
    
    gorilla1.throwSomething(gorilla2);
    gorilla1.throwSomething(gorilla2);
    gorilla1.throwSomething(gorilla2);
    gorilla1.eatBananas(gorilla2);
    gorilla1.eatBananas(gorilla2);
    gorilla1.climb(gorilla2);
    

}
```

}

Output:

Gorilla Throw something and will be decrease its energy level to -5

Gorilla has only 95 energy level left

Gorilla Throw something and will be decrease its energy level to -5

Gorilla has only 90 energy level left

Gorilla Throw something and will be decrease its energy level to -5

Gorilla has only 85 energy level left

Gorilla eat bananas and will be increase its energy level to +10

Gorilla has only 95 energy level left

Gorilla eat bananas and will be increase its energy level to +10

Gorilla has only 105 energy level left

Gorilla has climb and will be decrease its energy level to -10

Gorilla has only 95 energy level left

The problem here is that After the gorilla ate the 2nd banana, the energy level was exceeded to 100.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.min(100, newLevel)` should give you the lowest between `newLevel` and 100.

Comment: should I put it in the methods?

Comment: `this.level = Math.max(100, level);` in `setLevel` and in your constructor.

Comment: It get me an error

Comment: Wouldn't min be more appropriate?

Comment: It says that the method max is underfined for the type object

Comment: @Shawn Indeed. Fixed it.

Comment: @Boomchakamae2334 can you copy-paste the entire error message? The `Math` class doesn't need any dependency. You shouldn't have any issue with it.